# Rigid object behaving differently in Object and Edit mode?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Ok, so I'm a total noob at this. However, It seems weird that an object, in this case a modified cube shape, behaves differently when dropped from a hight depending on if it is viewed in object or edit mode. Im using the 2.8 Beta. In Edit mode, my object drops and hits a passive floor plane, bounces a bit and comes to rest. All good. When I switch to object mode however, the object drops and hits the floor normally, but after that it won't fall over! It just stands there on an awkward angle and moves a little in super slo-mo!?

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What is your question? This is really unconventional use,*Edit Mode* behavior is mostly irrelevant since it can't really be used for any purpose outside viewport previewing.

Comment: My question is, How can I make my object behave the same way in object mode, as it does in edit mode. Like you say, I want to render the object in Object mode :) In Edit mode, the physics are working perfecly..the shape falls, hits the ground plane, falls over and comes to rest flat on the ground. In Object mode it falls normally to the ground, but when it hits the ground it lands in the position of the above screenshot. It then starts to fall in slow motion. Really slow. What do you think is causing this. Is gravity only working normally on one axis?

Comment: I´ve tried adding a cube to the scene, and that behaves perfectly when dropped in object mode, so I take it it has something to do with my shape?

Comment: I ended up modelling a new shape, and now it works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I have just solved the problem!

I exported the object from my Blender file as an .obj file and imported it back. Now it behaves perfectly with physics and other stuff!

Comment: Exporting and re-eimporting is a destructive process and is not a solution. You will  lose materials, modifiers, animations and other data associated with your object.  Whatever it unintentionally changed can be achieved without exporting